# How to get a Java for loop to pull all API records in the selected criteria

Tags: java, android, api, parsing

I am an aspiring Android developer. I don't have a lot of experience in creating applications yet.

I have an API, and the code to call and retrieve the data. The issue I am having is it is only pulling the first record. When I run the debug tool I can see that it finds all three, but it is only printing the first one. Any help and guidance is very much appreciated.

### Here is my code:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

                JSONObject reportObject = parentObject.getJSONObject("report");
                String mReport = reportObject.getString("foods");

                JSONArray foodArray = reportObject.getJSONArray("foods");
                JSONObject mFood = foodArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String foodName = mFood.getString("name");
                String foodMeasure = mFood.getString("measure");

                JSONArray nutrientsArray = mFood.getJSONArray("nutrients");

                for(int i = 0; i < nutrientsArray.length(); ++i) {

                JSONObject nutrientObject = nutrientsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String nutrientName = nutrientObject.getString("nutrient");
                String nutrientValue = nutrientObject.getString("value");

                return foodName + "\nNutrient:  " + nutrientName + "\nMeasure: " + foodMeasure + "\nValue: " + nutrientValue;
            }
```

### Here is the API data:

[API database link](http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/?format=json&api_key=EfLRC6qyTM8aYtJdaA0Esb1yuThFQfvGeOUtQWNZ&nutrients=203&nutrients=204&nutrients=205)

```js
{
   "report": {
 "sr": "Legacy",
"groups": "All groups",
"subset": "All foods",
"end": 150,
"start": 0,
"total": 7524,
"foods": [
{
"ndbno": "09427",
"name": "Abiyuch, raw",
"weight": 114,
"measure": "0.5 cup",
"nutrients": [
{
"nutrient_id": "203",
"nutrient": "Protein",
"unit": "g",
"value": "1.71",
"gm": 1.5
},
{
"nutrient_id": "204",
"nutrient": "Total lipid (fat)",
"unit": "g",
"value": "0.11",
"gm": 0.1
},
{
"nutrient_id": "205",
"nutrient": "Carbohydrate, by difference",
"unit": "g",
"value": "20.06",
"gm": 17.6
}
]
},
```

### And here are my results(they are being parsed correctly)

```
foodName:"Abiych, raw" nutrientName: "Protein" foodMeasure: "0.5 cup" nutrientValue: "1.74"
```

How do I get it to pull and display the other two items from the API that are called?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop has a return statement. It quits `for` loop and the method after first iteration. Store results in an array and return the array out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using this. The for loop execution answer is what helped me see my error. Thank you!

```
StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
                        for(int i = 0; i < nutrientsArray.length(); ++i) {
                        JSONObject nutrientObject = nutrientsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nutrientName = nutrientObject.getString("nutrient");
                        String nutrientValue = nutrientObject.getString("value");
                        finalBufferedData.append( "\nNutrient:  " + nutrientName +
                                "\nMeasure: " + foodMeasure + "\nValue: " + nutrientValue +"\n "+"\n ");


                    }
                    return foodName + "\n" + finalBufferedData.toString();
```